# Get Complete data on dropdown in web site with using macro

Tags: excel, vba

normally I use an excel chart to upload my data to website. but I realized that in time new additions can be added to a dropdown and unfortunately, i dont know is there anything added or not. So I want to add refresh button to my excel sheet to refresh data inside my excel and get data from website dropdown menu.
below you may find the code in web site. by the way I cannot share the link because it is behind the firewall and credentials. so here is the code

```
        <select name="ddfener" id="ddlfener" tabindex="2" class="normalText">
    <option value="0">Select a fener....</option>
    <option value="81ca032h">ahmet</option>
    <option value="345">mehmet</option>
    <option value="123">ayse</option>
```

I need to download this data like

```
 81ca032h  ahmet
 345       mehmet
 123       ayse
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the macro for the values read out so that they end up in the right places in your Excel table. Everything else is in the comments of the macro:

```
Sub ReadDropdownValues()

  Dim browser As Object
  Dim url As String
  Dim nodeDropdown As Object
  Dim nodesOption As Object
  Dim optionTagNo As Long
  'Only for this demo
  'You write the single readed
  'values to your Excel table
  Dim result As String

  'Place your internal url here
  url = "file:///E:/testDropdown.htm"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  '
  'This could be problematic on the intranet due to security guidelines
  'Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  '
  'Try this instead to initialize the IE
  Set browser = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
  browser.Visible = False 'Set to 'True' to see the IE
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Get dropdown html structure
  On Error Resume Next
  Set nodeDropdown = browser.document.getElementByID("ddlfener")
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Check if object 'nodeDropdown' was build
  If Not nodeDropdown Is Nothing Then
    'Create node collection of option tags from object 'nodeDropdown'
    Set nodesOption = nodeDropdown.getElementsByTagName("option")

    'Loop through all option tags from, the second one
    '(The first one is only the placeholder 'Select a fener....')
    For optionTagNo = 1 To nodesOption.Length - 1
      'Get the value of the attribute 'value'
      result = result & Trim(nodesOption(optionTagNo).getAttribute("value"))
      'Insert tab only for demo string
      result = result & Chr(9)
      'Get dropdown value
      result = result & Trim(nodesOption(optionTagNo).innertext)
      'Insert new line only for demo string
      result = result & Chr(13)
    Next optionTagNo
  Else
    'If object 'nodeDropdown' wasn't build
    result = "Dropdown not found"
  End If

  'Clean up
  browser.Quit
  Set browser = Nothing
  Set nodeDropdown = Nothing
  Set nodesOption = Nothing

  'Show demo result
  MsgBox result
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Zwenn but unfortunately, gettin below error                                               Run-time Error'-2147417848(80010108)':
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients". by the way if i change browser to ie command as `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer`istead of browser and change all browser things to ie, also need to change   `Set nodeDropdown = browser.document.getElementByID("ddlfener") ` to  `Set nodeDropdown = ie.document.querySelector(("#ddlfener")`and now it is worked !!! thanks a lot

Comment: @SelpaqM Thanks for the feedback. Great that you got it working with the changes. Sometimes macros work slightly different depending on the environment they are running in.